# Undefined method `where' for Todo:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I get this error from todo_controller.rb

```
class TodoController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @todos = Todo.where(done: false)
    @todone = Todo.where(done: true)
  end

  def new
    @todo = Todo.new
  end

  def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:name, :done)
  end

  def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
    if @todo.save
      redirect_to todo_index_path, :notice => "Your todo item was created!"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    if @todo.update_attribute(:done, true)
      redirect_to todo_index_path, :notice => "Your todo item was marked as done!"
    else
      redirect_to todo_index_path, :notice => "Your todo item wasn't marked as done!"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    @todo.destroy
    redirect_to todo_index_path, :notice => "Your todo task has been deleted!"
  end
end
```

I googled it and found out that there was supposed to be a Module with the same name. I found it config/application.rb , and I change it to Module todoo, but I get the same error again.

Comment: Can you share you model code?

Comment: Is `Todo` a model (class) or module? Big difference. Sounds like you may have defined your model as a module.

Comment: show your Todo class (model)

Comment: Also, did you use `rails g controller` to generate this controller or manually create it? The standard naming convention for a Rails controller is to use a plural form of the object it's acting on behalf of - i.e. it should be `todos_controller.rb` and `class TodosController < ApplicationController`.

Comment: class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
end

That's in my model folder.

Comment: @Buno please add your model declaration to your question, as opposed to as a comment. It's much easier to follow for other people coming to this question. Also, please add the migration you used to create the `todos` table to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I just redid the app completely, and it worked. I guess that I did something manually where it should've been done by Rails automatically, and that where it all went wrong.

Comment: The Rails generators are your friends. :-)